# xr package not working properly

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I'm trying to use the `xr` package, and I'm having problems.

My document is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{ch04}

\begin{document}

Exercice - Page \pageref{ex3.1}    

\end{document}
```

The result is

> Exercice - Page 11example.1.6

The page is correct, but it is showing **example.1.6**. In the main file, this reference is from *Example 1.6*, but I don't understand why this information is appearing.

The same occurs if I use only `\ref{ex3.1}`, the result is **1.6example.1.6**.

Comment: does the external document use hyperref?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Yes, but if I use `zref-xr`, I have the error *Undefined control sequence. \zref*

Comment: you want xr-hyper  not xr

Comment: @DavidCarlisle xr-hyper only helps if the main document loads hyperref too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well yes there is that, I should try again to combine them but it's tricky:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wouldn't it be easier to redefine \pageref so that it does `\@secondofwhatever` instead of `\@secondoftwo`?